# Scala JVM Crash

Tags: java, scala, crash, jvm, dump

In the project in which I work we have a backend developed in Scala that uses play 2.6.0, scalike 2.5.2, mysql-connector-java 5.1.43. The jvm is the Oracle jdk 1.8_131. I have done a search but I have not found any topic that fits my problem.

I have obtained another log with jdk 1.8_192: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ehngl0ek19zciq0/hs_err_pid1281.log?dl=0

Log:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f1c350d3cc0, pid=1194, tid=0x00007f1b9218b700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_131-b11) (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# J 26048 C2 com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(Lcom/mysql/jdbc/Buffer;)V (467 bytes) @ 0x00007f1c350d3cc0 [0x00007f1c350d3ca0+0x20]


---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f1bb0036000):  JavaThread "application-custom-execution-contexts.database-2321" [_thread_in_Java, id=3976, stack(0x00007f1b9208b000,0x00007f1b9218c000)]

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), si_addr: 0x00007f1c350d3cc0

Instructions: (pc=0x00007f1c350d3cc0)
0x00007f1c350d3ca0:   44 8b 56 08 49 c1 e2 03 49 3b c2 0f 85 6f 21 f7
0x00007f1c350d3cb0:   fb 66 66 90 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 66 66 66 90
0x00007f1c350d3cc0:   89 84 24 00 c0 fe ff 55 48 83 ec 60 4c 8b d6 48
0x00007f1c350d3cd0:   89 54 24 08 44 8b 42 18 8b 6a 10 44 8b dd 41 ff 

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x00000005ac5bfb78 is an oop
com.mysql.jdbc.Buffer 
 - klass: 'com/mysql/jdbc/Buffer'
RBX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
RDX=0x00000005ac5bfb78 is an oop
com.mysql.jdbc.Buffer 
 - klass: 'com/mysql/jdbc/Buffer'
RSP=0x00007f1b9218a028 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f1bb0036000
RBP=0x00000005ac5bfb78 is an oop
com.mysql.jdbc.Buffer 
 - klass: 'com/mysql/jdbc/Buffer'
RSI=0x00000005a3d816d0 is an oop
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO 
 - klass: 'com/mysql/jdbc/MysqlIO'
RDI=0x00000005a3d85e40 is pointing into object: 0x00000005a3d85e38
[B 
 - klass: {type array byte}
 - length: 16384
R8 =0x00000005a3d816d0 is an oop
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO 
 - klass: 'com/mysql/jdbc/MysqlIO'
R9 =0x00000000b58b7f73 is an unknown value
R10=0x00000005a3d7d088 is an oop
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection 
 - klass: 'com/mysql/jdbc/JDBC4Connection'
R11=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000000000007 is an unknown value
R14=0x00000005a3d85e10 is an oop
com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream 
 - klass: 'com/mysql/jdbc/util/ReadAheadInputStream'
R15=0x00007f1bb0036000 is a thread


Stack: [0x00007f1b9208b000,0x00007f1b9218c000],  sp=0x00007f1b9218a028,  free space=1020k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
J 26048 C2 com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(Lcom/mysql/jdbc/Buffer;)V (467 bytes) @ 0x00007f1c350d3cc0 [0x00007f1c350d3ca0+0x20]
C  0x00000005bac1fd28


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00007f1c040f8800 JavaThread "application-custom-execution-contexts.database-2342" [_thread_blocked, id=3995, stack(0x00007f1b8f263000,0x00007f1b8f364000)]
  0x00007f1c040ff000 JavaThread "application-custom-execution-contexts.database-2341" [_thread_blocked, id=3994, stack(0x00007f1b8f564000,0x00007f1b8f665000)]
  0x00007f1c040f9800 JavaThread "application-custom-execution-contexts.database-2340" [_thread_blocked, id=3993, stack(0x00007f1b8f968000,0x00007f1b8fa69000)]
  0x00007f1c040f5800 JavaThread "application-custom-execution-contexts.database-2338" [_thread_blocked, id=3992, stack(0x00007f1b8fa69000,0x00007f1b8fb6a000)]
  0x00007f1c0016a800 JavaThread "application-custom-execution-contexts.database-2339" [_thread_blocked, id=3991, stack(0x00007f1b8fd6c000,0x00007f1b8fe6d000)]
  0x00007f1c1425a000 JavaThread "application-custom-execution-contexts.database-2337" [_thread_blocked, id=3990, stack(0x00007f1b8ff6e000,0x00007f1b9006f000)]
  0x00007f1c1416c800 JavaThread "application-custom-execution-


VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 garbage-first heap   total 524288K, used 247808K [0x00000005a0000000, 0x00000005a0200800, 0x00000007c0000000)
  region size 2048K, 52 young (106496K), 9 survivors (18432K)
 Metaspace       used 132703K, capacity 147524K, committed 147840K, reserved 1179648K
  class space    used 15698K, capacity 16649K, committed 16768K, reserved 1048576K

Heap Regions: (Y=young(eden), SU=young(survivor), HS=humongous(starts), 
...

Card table byte_map: [0x00007f1bf0bff000,0x00007f1bf1cff000] byte_map_base: 0x00007f1bedeff000

Marking Bits (Prev, Next): (CMBitMap*) 0x00007f1c4005a4d0, (CMBitMap*) 0x00007f1c4005a478
 Prev Bits: [0x00007f1bd3000000, 0x00007f1bdb800000)
 Next Bits: [0x00007f1bdb800000, 0x00007f1be4000000)

Polling page: 0x00007f1c47c71000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=80836Kb max_used=81052Kb free=164923Kb
 bounds [0x00007f1c31000000, 0x00007f1c35fc0000, 0x00007f1c40000000]
 total_blobs=27146 nmethods=25929 adapters=1127
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 5270.469 Thread 0x00007f1c402cc800 33431       3       play.core.routing.RouteParams$$Lambda$1757/2077515981::apply (12 bytes)
Event: 5270.470 Thread 0x00007f1c402cc800 nmethod 33431 0x00007f1c348cf150 code [0x00007f1c348cf400, 0x00007f1c348d0888]
Event: 5270.472 Thread 0x00007f1c402cc800 33432       3       play.core.routing.RouteParams::$anonfun$fromQuery$1 (22 bytes)
Event: 5270.472 Thread 0x00007f1c402cc800 nmethod 33432 0x00007f1c348cd010 code [0x00007f1c348cd2c0, 0x00007f1c348ce6a8]
Event: 5270.474 Thread 0x00007f1c402cc800 33435       3       scala.collection.immutable.VectorPointer::stabilize$ (6 bytes)
Event: 5270.474 Thread 0x00007f1c402cc800 nmethod 33435 0x00007f1c318e2b50 code [0x00007f1c318e2cc0, 0x00007f1c318e2e28]
Event: 5270.476 Thread 0x00007f1c402cc800 33433       3       play.core.routing.RouteParams$$Lambda$2505/822556919::get$Lambda (9 bytes)
Event: 5270.476 Thread 0x00007f1c402cc800 nmethod 33433 0x00007f1c319a5ed0 code [0x00007f1c319a6040, 0x00007f1c319a62f0]
Event: 5270.478 Thread 0x00007f1c402cc800 33434       3       play.core.routing.RouteParams$$Lambda$2505/822556919::<init> (10 bytes)
Event: 5270.478 Thread 0x00007f1c402cc800 nmethod 33434 0x00007f1c32089dd0 code [0x00007f1c32089f40, 0x00007f1c3208a150]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 5163.800 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=390 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 524288K, used 457683K [0x00000005a0000000, 0x00000005a0200800, 0x00000007c0000000)
  region size 2048K, 153 young (313344K), 4 survivors (8192K)
 Metaspace       used 132649K, capacity 147524K, committed 147840K, reserved 1179648K
  class space    used 15698K, capacity 16649K, committed 16768K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 5163.820 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=391 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 524288K, used 162183K [0x00000005a0000000, 0x00000005a0200800, 0x00000007c0000000)
  region size 2048K, 9 young (18432K), 9 survivors (18432K)
 Metaspace       used 132649K, capacity 147524K, committed 147840K, reserved 1179648K
  class space    used 15698K, capacity 16649K, committed 16768K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 5188.222 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=391 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 524288K, used 450951K [0x00000005a0000000, 0x00000005a0200800, 0x00000007c0000000)
  region size 2048K, 150 young (307200K), 9 survivors (18432K)
 Metaspace       used 132650K, capacity 147524K, committed 147840K, reserved 1179648K
  class space    used 15698K, capacity 16649K, committed 16768K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 5188.255 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=392 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 524288K, used 159777K [0x00000005a0000000, 0x00000005a0200800, 0x00000007c0000000)
  region size 2048K, 8 young (16384K), 8 survivors (16384K)
 Metaspace       used 132650K, capacity 147524K, committed 147840K, reserved 1179648K
  class space    used 15698K, capacity 16649K, committed 16768K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 5209.076 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=392 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 524288K, used 452641K [0x00000005a0000000, 0x00000005a0200800, 0x00000007c0000000)
  region size 2048K, 151 young (309248K), 8 survivors (16384K)
 Metaspace       used 132654K, capacity 147524K, committed 147840K, reserved 1179648K
  class space    used 15698K, capacity 16649K, committed 16768K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 5209.090 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=393 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 524288K, used 159744K [0x00000005a0000000, 0x00000005a0200800, 0x00000007c0000000)
  region size 2048K, 8 young (16384K), 8 survivors (16384K)
 Metaspace       used 132654K, capacity 147524K, committed 147840K, reserved 1179648K
  class space    used 15698K, capacity 16649K, committed 16768K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 5235.145 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=393 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 524288K, used 452608K [0x00000005a0000000, 0x00000005a0200800, 0x00000007c0000000)
  region size 2048K, 151 young (309248K), 8 survivors (16384K)
 Metaspace       used 132656K, capacity 147524K, committed 147840K, reserved 1179648K
  class space    used 15698K, capacity 16649K, committed 16768K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 5235.160 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=394 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 524288K, used 161792K [0x00000005a0000000, 0x00000005a0200800, 0x00000007c0000000)
  region size 2048K, 9 young (18432K), 9 survivors (18432K)
 Metaspace       used 132656K, capacity 147524K, committed 147840K, reserved 1179648K
  class space    used 15698K, capacity 16649K, committed 16768K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 5265.832 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=394 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 524288K, used 450560K [0x00000005a0000000, 0x00000005a0200800, 0x00000007c0000000)
  region size 2048K, 150 young (307200K), 9 survivors (18432K)
 Metaspace       used 132699K, capacity 147524K, committed 147840K, reserved 1179648K
  class space    used 15698K, capacity 16649K, committed 16768K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 5265.850 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=395 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 524288K, used 161792K [0x00000005a0000000, 0x00000005a0200800, 0x00000007c0000000)
  region size 2048K, 9 young (18432K), 9 survivors (18432K)
 Metaspace       used 132699K, capacity 147524K, committed 147840K, reserved 1179648K
  class space    used 15698K, capacity 16649K, committed 16768K, reserved 1048576K
}

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 5045.836 Thread 0x00007f1c20186800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007f1c35f4971c method=users.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1.applyOrElse(Lplay/api/mvc/RequestHeader;Lscala/Function1;)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 1383
Event: 5060.118 Thread 0x00007f1bfc117800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00007f1c356e5c4c method=java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$Sync.tryReleaseShared(I)Z @ 130
Event: 5126.865 Thread 0x00007f1c425a1800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007f1c35dff214 method=polls.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1.applyOrElse(Lplay/api/mvc/RequestHeader;Lscala/Function1;)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 155
Event: 5126.867 Thread 0x00007f1c425a1800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007f1c353c5b9c method=router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1.applyOrElse(Lplay/api/mvc/RequestHeader;Lscala/Function1;)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 1337
Event: 5126.881 Thread 0x00007f1c0411d000 Uncommon trap: reason=range_check action=make_not_entrant pc=0x00007f1c355da160 method=jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.Type.getType([CI)Ljdk/internal/org/objectweb/asm/Type; @ 2
Event: 5140.580 Thread 0x00007f1bfc10b800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007f1c35dff214 method=polls.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1.applyOrElse(Lplay/api/mvc/RequestHeader;Lscala/Function1;)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 155
Event: 5140.580 Thread 0x00007f1bfc10b800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007f1c353c5b9c method=router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1.applyOrElse(Lplay/api/mvc/RequestHeader;Lscala/Function1;)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 1337
Event: 5208.353 Thread 0x00007f1c20186800 Uncommon trap: reason=speculate_class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007f1c3517666c method=scala.Option.getOrElse(Lscala/Function0;)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 1
Event: 5219.043 Thread 0x00007f1c425a1800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007f1c34adfec4 method=services.internal.CommentInternalServiceImpl$$Lambda$2930/225655434.apply(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 21
Event: 5219.043 Thread 0x00007f1c425a1800 Uncommon trap: reason=speculate_class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007f1c34a6f868 method=scala.Option.exists(Lscala/Function1;)Z @ 1

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 5249.703 Thread 0x00007f1c410a7800 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x00000005b8c8f5b0) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk8u131/8869/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 5249.703 Thread 0x00007f1c410a7800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000005b8c97220) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk8u131/8869/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp, line 1390]
Event: 5249.703 Thread 0x00007f1c410a7800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000005b8c97618) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk8u131/8869/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp, line 1390]
Event: 5249.704 Thread 0x00007f1c410a7800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000005b8ca4e40) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk8u131/8869/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp, line 1390]
Event: 5249.704 Thread 0x00007f1c410a7800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000005b8ca5238) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk8u131/8869/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp, line 1390]
Event: 5249.704 Thread 0x00007f1c410a7800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000005b8cc8720) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk8u131/8869/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp, line 1390]
Event: 5249.704 Thread 0x00007f1c410a7800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000005b8cc8b18) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk8u131/8869/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp, line 1390]
Event: 5249.704 Thread 0x00007f1c410a7800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000005b8cd6a40) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk8u131/8869/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp, line 1390]
Event: 5249.704 Thread 0x00007f1c410a7800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000005b8cd6e38) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk8u131/8869/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp, line 1390]
Event: 5249.704 Thread 0x00007f1c410a7800 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x00000005b8cdd858) thrown at [/HUDSON/workspace/8-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk8u131/8869/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 709]



VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Duser.dir=/opt/project-core-rest/core -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:ConcGCThreads=4 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=8 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:/var/log/project-core-rest/gc.log -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=100 -XX:GCLogFileSize=49M -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=16000 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=16000 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost -Dconfig.file=/opt/project-core-rest/config/project-core-rest.conf -Dlogger.resource=logback-pro.xml -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dpidfile.path=/var/run/project.com/project-core-rest.pid -Duser.timezone=GMT -XX:ErrorFile=/usr/share/NAS/errors/hs_err_pid%p.log -Xms512M -Xmx8704M 
java_command: play.core.server.ProdServerStart
java_class_path (initial): /opt/project-core-rest/core/lib/../conf/:/opt/project-core-rest/core/lib/com.project.project-1.2.18-sans-externalized.jar:/opt/project-core-rest/core/lib/scala-faker_2.12-0.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:/opt/project-core-rest/core/lib/org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.12.3.jar:/opt/project-core-rest/core/lib/com.sksamuel.scapegoat.scalac-scapegoat-plugin_2.12-1.3.1.jar:/opt/project-core-rest/core/lib/org.scala-lang.scala-reflect-2.12.3.jar:/opt/project-core-rest/core/lib/org.scala-lang.modules.scala-xml_2.12-1.0.6.jar:/opt/project-core-rest/core/lib/com.typesafe.play.twirl-api_2.12-1.3.3.jar:/opt/project-core-rest/core/lib/com.typesafe.play.play-server_2.12-2.6.2.jar:/opt/project-core-rest/core/lib/com.typesafe.play.play_2.12-2.6.2.jar:/opt/project-core-rest/core/lib/com.typesafe.play.build-link-2.6.2.jar:/opt/project-core-rest/core/lib/com.typesafe.play.play-exceptions-2.6.2.jar:/opt/project-core-rest/core/lib/com.typesafe.play.play-netty-utils-2.6.2.jar:/opt/project-core-rest/core/lib/org.slf4j.slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/opt/project-core-rest/core/lib/org.slf4j.jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:/opt/project-core-rest/core/lib/org.slf4j.jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:/opt/project-core-rest/core/lib/com.typesafe.play.play-streams_2.12-2.6.2.jar:/opt/project-core-rest/core/lib/org.reactivestreams.reactive-streams-1.0.0.jar:/opt/project-core-rest/core/lib/com.typesafe.akka.akka-stream_2.12-2.5.3.jar:/opt/project-core-rest/core/lib/com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.12-2.5.3.jar:/opt/project-core-rest/core/lib/com.typesafe.config-1.3.1.jar:/opt/project-core-rest/core/lib/org.scala-lang.modules.scala-java8-compat_2.12-0.8.0.jar:/opt/project-core-rest/core/lib/org.scala-lang.modules.scala-parser-combinators_2.12-1.0.6.jar:/opt/project-core-rest/core/lib/com.typesafe.akka.akka-slf4j_2.12-2.5.3.jar:/opt/project-core-rest/core/lib/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core-2.8.9.jar:/opt/project-core-rest/core/lib/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations-2.8.9.jar:/opt/project-core-r
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"

uname:Linux 3.16.0-7-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.59-1 (2018-10-03) x86_64
libc:glibc 2.19 NPTL 2.19 
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE infinity, NPROC 62408, NOFILE 65536, AS infinity
load average:0.09 0.15 0.16

/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:       15994192 kB
MemFree:        11119944 kB
MemAvailable:   14589100 kB
Buffers:           20696 kB
Cached:          3591220 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          1227552 kB
Inactive:        3491436 kB
Active(anon):    1107188 kB
Inactive(anon):     8304 kB
Active(file):     120364 kB
Inactive(file):  3483132 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:               268 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       1107096 kB
Mapped:            49360 kB
Shmem:              8416 kB
Slab:              81720 kB
SReclaimable:      69188 kB
SUnreclaim:        12532 kB
KernelStack:        4080 kB
PageTables:         4376 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     7997096 kB
Committed_AS:    1197444 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:       29936 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359707655 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       51176 kB
DirectMap2M:     2613248 kB
DirectMap1G:    13631488 kB


Memory: 4k page, physical 15994192k(11119944k free), swap 0k(0k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_131-b11), built on Mar 15 2017 01:23:40 by "java_re" with gcc 4.3.0 20080428 (Red Hat 4.3.0-8)

time: Mon Dec  3 16:54:03 2018
elapsed time: 5272 seconds (0d 1h 27m 52s)
```

I have deleted part of the log, if you need something in particular I write it. Thanks in advance for your help.

An example of code that interacts with the BBDD, the rest of the accesses to tables are similar.

```
package models.generated

import models.generated.TableQuizQuestion.cqq
import scalikejdbc._

case class TableQuiz(
    TableId: Long,
    TableQuizCategoryId: Option[Long] = None,
    randomizeQuestions: Boolean,
    timeSecondsLimit: Option[Int] = None,
    totalAnswerLimit: Option[Int] = None,
    questionsDisposition: String
) {

  def save()(implicit session: DBSession): TableQuiz = TableQuiz.save(this)(session)

  def destroy(): Int = TableQuiz.destroy(this)

}

object TableQuiz extends SQLSyntaxSupport[TableQuiz] {

  override val tableName = "Table_QUIZ"

  override val columns = Seq("Table_id", "Table_quiz_category_id", "randomize_questions", "time_seconds_limit", "total_answer_limit", "questions_disposition")

  def apply(cq: SyntaxProvider[TableQuiz])(rs: WrappedResultSet): TableQuiz = apply(cq.resultName)(rs)
  def apply(cq: ResultName[TableQuiz])(rs: WrappedResultSet): TableQuiz = new TableQuiz(
    TableId = rs.get(cq.TableId),
    TableQuizCategoryId = rs.get(cq.TableQuizCategoryId),
    randomizeQuestions = rs.get(cq.randomizeQuestions),
    timeSecondsLimit = rs.get(cq.timeSecondsLimit),
    totalAnswerLimit = rs.get(cq.totalAnswerLimit),
    questionsDisposition = rs.get(cq.questionsDisposition)
  )

  val cq = TableQuiz.syntax("cq")

  override val autoSession = AutoSession

  def find(TableId: Long)(implicit session: DBSession): Option[TableQuiz] = {
    withSQL {
      select.from(TableQuiz as cq).where.eq(cq.TableId, TableId)
    }.map(TableQuiz(cq.resultName)).single.apply()
  }

  def findAll()(implicit session: DBSession): List[TableQuiz] = {
    withSQL(select.from(TableQuiz as cq)).map(TableQuiz(cq.resultName)).list.apply()
  }

  def countAll()(implicit session: DBSession): Long = {
    withSQL(select(sqls.count).from(TableQuiz as cq)).map(rs => rs.long(1)).single.apply().get
  }

  def findBy(where: SQLSyntax)(implicit session: DBSession): Option[TableQuiz] = {
    withSQL {
      select.from(TableQuiz as cq).where.append(where)
    }.map(TableQuiz(cq.resultName)).single.apply()
  }

  def findAllBy(where: SQLSyntax)(implicit session: DBSession): List[TableQuiz] = {
    withSQL {
      select.from(TableQuiz as cq).where.append(where)
    }.map(TableQuiz(cq.resultName)).list.apply()
  }

  def countBy(where: SQLSyntax)(implicit session: DBSession): Long = {
    withSQL {
      select(sqls.count).from(TableQuiz as cq).where.append(where)
    }.map(_.long(1)).single.apply().get
  }

  def create(
    TableId: Long,
    TableQuizCategoryId: Option[Long] = None,
    randomizeQuestions: Boolean,
    timeSecondsLimit: Option[Int] = None,
    totalAnswerLimit: Option[Int] = None,
    questionsDisposition: String
  )(implicit session: DBSession): TableQuiz = {
    withSQL {
      insert.into(TableQuiz).namedValues(
        column.TableId -> TableId,
        column.TableQuizCategoryId -> TableQuizCategoryId,
        column.randomizeQuestions -> randomizeQuestions,
        column.timeSecondsLimit -> timeSecondsLimit,
        column.totalAnswerLimit -> totalAnswerLimit,
        column.questionsDisposition -> questionsDisposition
      )
    }.update.apply()

    TableQuiz(
      TableId = TableId,
      TableQuizCategoryId = TableQuizCategoryId,
      randomizeQuestions = randomizeQuestions,
      timeSecondsLimit = timeSecondsLimit,
      totalAnswerLimit = totalAnswerLimit,
      questionsDisposition = questionsDisposition
    )
  }

  def batchInsert(entities: Seq[TableQuiz])(implicit session: DBSession): List[Int] = {
    val params: Seq[Seq[(Symbol, Any)]] = entities.map(entity =>
      Seq(
        'TableId -> entity.TableId,
        'TableQuizCategoryId -> entity.TableQuizCategoryId,
        'randomizeQuestions -> entity.randomizeQuestions,
        'timeSecondsLimit -> entity.timeSecondsLimit,
        'totalAnswerLimit -> entity.totalAnswerLimit,
        'questionsDisposition -> entity.questionsDisposition
      ))
    SQL("""insert into Table_QUIZ(
      Table_id,
      Table_quiz_category_id,
      randomize_questions,
      time_seconds_limit,
      total_answer_limit,
      questions_disposition
    ) values (
      {TableId},
      {TableQuizCategoryId},
      {randomizeQuestions},
      {timeSecondsLimit},
      {totalAnswerLimit},
      {questionsDisposition}
    )""").batchByName(params: _*).apply[List]()
  }

  def save(entity: TableQuiz)(implicit session: DBSession): TableQuiz = {
    withSQL {
      update(TableQuiz).set(
        column.TableId -> entity.TableId,
        column.TableQuizCategoryId -> entity.TableQuizCategoryId,
        column.randomizeQuestions -> entity.randomizeQuestions,
        column.timeSecondsLimit -> entity.timeSecondsLimit,
        column.totalAnswerLimit -> entity.totalAnswerLimit,
        column.questionsDisposition -> entity.questionsDisposition
      ).where.eq(column.TableId, entity.TableId)
    }.update.apply()
    entity
  }

  def destroy(entity: TableQuiz): Int = {
    DB localTx { implicit session =>
      withSQL {
        delete.from(TableQuiz).where.eq(column.TableId, entity.TableId)
      }.update.apply()
    }
  }

  /*
  delete cq from Table_QUIZ cq
    join Table c on c.id = cq.Table_id
    and c.owner_id = @my_user_id;
   */
  def findByUserId(userId: Long): List[TableQuiz] = {
    DB localTx { implicit session =>
      withSQL {
        select
          .from(TableQuiz as TableQuiz.cq)
          .join(Table as Table.c)
          .on(TableQuiz.cq.column("Table_id"), Table.c.column("id"))
          .where.append(sqls.eq(Table.c.ownerId, userId))
      }.map(TableQuiz(cq.resultName)).list().apply()
    }
  }

  def deleteByUserId(userId: Long)(implicit session: DBSession): Int = {
    //disableSafeMode()
    val subQuery: SQLSyntax =
      select(Table.c.column("id"))
        .from(Table as Table.c)
        .where.append(sqls.eq(Table.c.ownerId, userId)).toSQLSyntax

    val where = sqls.in(TableQuiz.column.TableId, subQuery)
    withSQL { delete.from(TableQuiz).where(where)}.update.apply()
  }

}
```

Comment: It seems a problem with the buffer. Add the code which executes the databases operations to see if there can be some sync problems.

Comment: The problem is that I do not know what is the exact code in which the problem occurs. In the trace I do not see anything else and no reference is made to any of the project classes. In addition, the project is huge.

Comment: EmiCareOfCell44 is asking for the code that interacts with the database. If you want him or other people here on stackoverflow to help, you need to provide that code. I'd suggest posting every part of the code related to the database. Getting / storing data. Perhaps even the settings.

Comment: Since the crash seems to be inside the MySql connector, the obvious test is to try to update to the latest one and see if the issue is fixed.

Comment: I'm going to update the connector to 5.1.47 and the jdk to 1.8_192.

I can not update the connector to 8 since the version of scalikejdbc is 2.5.2 and I think it is not compatible.

In a while I will also put the code of one of the classes that access to BBDD so you can see it.

Thank you.

Comment: Important sections *Instructions* and *Dynamic libraries* are missing in the crash log.

Comment: It seems a problem in the logic. And it has to do with one native module of the MySql connector.  It might be a surprise if updating the version fix the problem, but without the code ... no one knows ...

Comment: Hi EmiCareOfCell44, I added the code in the message. I added the Intructions section in the log, but Dynamic Libraries does not fit in the message. Can I attach the complete file in any way?

Comment: You can upload the complete file to Dropbox or something and post a link here. *Instructions* section gave me some hint, but it's still unclear without the rest of the dump.

Comment: Hi, this is a new log file https://www.dropbox.com/s/hbwlr20c1thtkg2/hs_err_pid1166.log?dl=0 I hope you have enough information

Comment: I suggest reducing the problem to the bare minimum code which still shows the crash. I know it is not easy, but in my experience it is the best way to move forward.

Comment: The last crash log looks very suspicious: SEGV happens at the instruction that does not access memory at all. I can only imagine this happens due to hardware failure (check DRAM) or because .so library is overwritten while the program is running.

Comment: Thanks apangin. 
A hardware problem can not be because they are instances of aws. On the other hand, I can not imagine how the .so library can be overwritten but I will investigate about it.